# Ctrl-c kills shell when pipeline is used in input redirection subshell

Tags: bash, pipe, process-substitution

If I run a command like:

```
cat <(echo 1 | pv) | pv
cat <(echo 1 | pv) | less
cat <(echo 1 | pv) | cat
```

The command seems to run forever.  Entering `^C` (SIGINT) kills the entire shell instead of just the commands executed.  Why is this the case?

---

Relevant output of `ps xf` from another shell on minimal case `cat <(pv) | less`:

```
Ss  /bin/bash
S+   \_ cat /dev/fd/XX
S    |   \_ /bin/bash
T    |       \_ pv
S+   \_ less
```

With these file descriptors open:

**bash**

```
0 -> /dev/pts/YY
1 -> /dev/pts/YY
2 -> /dev/pts/YY
255 -> /dev/pts/YY
```

**cat /dev/fd/ZZ**

```
0 -> /dev/pts/YY
1 -> pipe:[RRRRRRRR]
2 -> /dev/pts/YY
3 -> pipe:[QQQQQQQQ]
ZZ -> pipe:[QQQQQQQQ]
```

**bash**

```
0 -> /dev/pts/YY
1 -> pipe:[QQQQQQQQ]
2 -> /dev/pts/YY
255 -> /dev/pts/YY
```

**pv**

```
0 -> /dev/pts/YY
1 -> pipe:[QQQQQQQQ]
2 -> /dev/pts/YY
```

**less**

```
0 -> pipe:[RRRRRRRR]
1 -> /dev/pts/YY
2 -> /dev/pts/YY
3 -> /dev/tty
```

---

Using the original example, `cat <(echo 1 | pv) | less` (this also happens when `echo` is not a bash builtin but another program like `dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 count=1`:

```
Ss   /bin/bash
S+    \_ cat /dev/fd/63
S     |   \_ /bin/bash
T     |       \_ pv
S+    \_ less
```

**bash**

```
0 -> /dev/pts/18
1 -> /dev/pts/18
2 -> /dev/pts/18
255 -> /dev/pts/18
```

**cat /dev/fd/63**

```
0 -> /dev/pts/18
1 -> pipe:[36932796]
2 -> /dev/pts/18
3 -> pipe:[36929317]
63 -> pipe:[36929317]
```

**bash**

```
0 -> /dev/pts/18
1 -> pipe:[36929317]
2 -> /dev/pts/18
255 -> /dev/pts/18
```

**pv**

```
0 -> pipe:[36930391]
1 -> pipe:[36929317]
2 -> /dev/pts/18
```

**less**

```
0 -> pipe:[36932796]
1 -> /dev/pts/18
2 -> /dev/pts/18
3 -> /dev/tty
```

Comment: Entire shell? i just tried it on my machine , and it works as expected , CTRL-C just exits the command and gives me the prompt back

Comment: What version of bash are you running, and what operating system?

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: Linux $HOST 3.13.0-67-generic #110-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 23 13:24:41 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: http://imgur.com/l9ueDe3 ^C happens around :04

Comment: Is there a SIGPIPE leaking from the subshell or something?

Comment: Running `bash` under `strace` might be informative to determine which signals are going where.

Comment: When you say “entire shell”, do you mean the terminal-emulation-window as well?

Comment: @richard - thats an excellent question.

Comment: It appears to kill the current terminal. If the current terminal is the only terminal in the emulator (i.e. gnome-terminal) then the emulator window also closes, though I suspect simply because the last terminal was closed.

Comment: then its probably sending HUP when the foreground process group  dies - and so my answer is at least a little incorrect. the parent shell still handles INT - which felt iffy when i wrote it - but not HUP. everything dies at a HUP. but the INT is not handled by the process substitution shell as it would be for an interactive shell, and it just dies and so the tty's foreground process dies and it sends HUP.

Comment: A couple more points: `cat <(echo 1 | sleep 99999) | cat` doesn't kill the shell when you type ^C. But `cat <(echo 1 | stty cooked <&2) | cat` does. What `pv` and `stty` have in common (and maybe that's significant here)  is that they immediately get stopped by SIGTTOU when they try to change tty settings, because the tty's pgrp has been set by the shell to the pid of the first cat, while the processes inside the process substitution parentheses are not in that pgrp.

Comment: And here's a minimal example that exhibits the problem: `cat <(pv) | cat`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: Note about the minimal example, `pv` is trying to interactively read from `stdin` (the shell).  Normally this does not cause `pv` to self terminate until EOF (Ctrl-D) like `echo 1 | pv` would.  It does reproduce the effect, though I'm not sure if the inner workings are the same.

Comment: @arcyqwerty - why in hell would it do that? that's madness - it's trying to read on fd 2? 1 and 2 are both pipes according your charts and stuff. what exactly are you trying to do with it, anyway?

Comment: Which one is trying to read off fd2?  Inputs to everything should be fd0 except for cat which uses the fd argument substituted by bash subshell.  fd0 can be a pipe if stdin is piped in (i.e. echo piped to pv, cat piped to less).  The examples here are on a different ubuntu machine, if that's relevant: `Linux $HOST 3.13.0-68-generic #111-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 18:17:06 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: @arcyqwerty - well, you just said it was actively trying to read the tty. and your thing says its got pipes on 1 and 0 - so im asking you - what is it doing there? or else why do you say its trying to read the tty?

Comment: @mikeserv: The first example `... <(pv) ...` has fd0 (stdin) reading from the pty (terminal).  This was in response to @MarkPlotnick's minimal example comment. The second example with the pipes is the examples from the original post.

Comment: oh, that makes more sense, of course. sorry about that. and yeah - in that exmple it would because it starts before anything else.

Comment: @arcyqwerty In `cat <(pv) | cat`, pv never gets a chance to read from stdin. It gets stopped with SIGTTOU very early on. Same behavior as in the larger examples. In fact, the code in pv's main explicitly sets TOSTOP on the tty that's on fd 2, with the comment "Set terminal option TOSTOP so we get signal SIGTTOU if we try to write to the terminal while backgrounded." As Mike said, bash may not be equipped to correctly handle job control signals inside a process substitution context.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: this might actually be the case for why `pv` is in `T` (stopped) state and explains why the entire pipeline is stalled.

Comment: BTW, as a workaround, `cat <(echo 1 | pv 2> >(cat) ) | whatever` appears to work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the info. That seems to prove your previous comment that `pv` is coded for `SIGTTOU` which stops the process when it can't write to terminal, causing the stall.  I'm still not entirely sure why Ctrl-C kills the parent shell since `pv` should have been successfully spawned and backgrounded by this point and the appropriate input/output already set.

Comment: I ran strace on the whole pipeline in your first example.  What kills the shell when I type Ctrl-C is that the kernel is sending it ( and other processes in its pgrp) SIGHUP.  I'm not sure why the SIGHUP is being sent.

Comment: Does that seem in line with @mikeserv's answer if the pgid of the child processes are the same as the parent shell?

Comment: @arcyqwerty - don't do 2> - that would work because it's not buffered. you can watch it break *(and not break)* like: `alias pchk='PS4='\''$PPID: $$: '\'' sh -cx '\''"$0" "$@"'\'' '\npchk cat < <(pchk echo | pchk pv) | pchk cat`. That will print the subshell's PID and the command's PID to stderr for each command run. You need to replace the `\n` with an actual newline, though. and if you do: `{ pchk cat; } < <(pchk echo|pchk pv)|pchk cat` you'll find it works without having to redirect stderr *(which you should almost never do except to capture actual errors)*.

Answer (score 3):

It happens because the `<(` process `)` isn't properly job-controlled - it's just forked and forgot. That doesn't matter most of the time, because *almost* as soon as it is born that process is placed in a separate process group and backgrounded. For the *instant* that the shell requires to open input and output for that process, however, that is the tty's foreground process group, and, as such, vulnerable to SIGINT - unless it is otherwise trapped or ignored as your interactive shell generally does.

The thing is, though: you have a pipe deadlock there. When the parent attempts to open output for that process the pipe blocks. It never gets the chance to change the process group and all the rest because when you *`CTRL+C`* the foreground group is killed - it's sent SIGINT - and when the foreground group dies and the parent cannot resume control because it's still blocked on a pipe, the terminal sends a HUP because there's nobody home. *kaboom*

You need a writer first, then a reader for every pipe you open before you can open another.

Comment: This sounds like it's correct but I'm not entirely comprehending. From what I understand so far, `echo` has input: `stdin` and output: `pipe1`, `pv` has input: `pipe1` and output: `/dev/fd/XX`, `cat` has input: `/dev/fd/XX` and output: `pipe2`, `{pv,less,cat}` has input: `pipe2` and output: `stdout`.  Which one(s) is deadlocked?

Comment: no. @arcyqwerty - it doesn't happen like that. the parent shell opens two subshells and connects i/o betwixt them via a pipe. the parent cant relinquish the pipe between them until the writing subshell opens it, too. but the writing subshell is busy opening its own subshell for the `<()` thing. and that subshell is waiting for `cat`. or maybe deeper - because that one opens two more subshells for its private pipeline, and then `echo`, `pv` or whatever. it goes deep. what's wrong with `echo 1 | pv | pv`?

Comment: Is the outer pipe or the `<(...)` subshell evaluated first?  I'm not sure what order things are happening in.  Best guess (using `less` example for unambiguity): 1. Shell spawns `echo` and `pv`, connects them with a pipe.  Spawns `cat` with input as output of the `<(...)` subshell and spawns `less`.  Tries to connect `cat` and `less` with a pipe.  OR 2. Shell spawns `cat <(...)` and `less`.  `cat <(...)` includes a subshell so it spawns a subshell with `echo` and `pv` connected by a pipe.  The output of this subshell is redirected to cat. `cat` and `less` are connected via pipe.

Comment: @arcyqwerty - well... `echo "$$" "$PPID"; echo "$(echo "$$" "$PPID")"; sh -c 'echo "$$" "$PPID"'; echo "$(sh -c 'echo "$PPID"')"; echo "$(exec sh -c 'echo "$PPID")"` - if you can figure out the differences between the various PIDs printed by that mess, then the following might be a helpful way to troubleshoot: `cat <(exec sh -c 'echo "$PPID"') | cat <(exec sh -c 'echo "$PPID"') -` - unless that deadlocks, too.

Comment: I've updated the question with some additional information that may shed light onto this. I'm not entirely sure how to parse the info though.  My best guess is that `pv` is being stopped due to some job control issue maybe having to do with pipes as well

Comment: @arcyqwerty - yeah, certainly im curious based on the other thing you said. `pv` does *buffer* though - definitely it does that. and so if a process buffers enough that interrupts a data flow then an entire pipeline can be brought to a halt because some other processes in the pipeline willl and stop and wait for input. sometimes all that is needed is a little kickoff. `cat <( echo; echo | pv ) | less`. `less` buffers, too, by the way, and it *always* connects to the terminal.

Comment: `cat <(echo; echo | pv) | less`, `cat <(cat /usr/share/dict/words | pv) | less`, and `cat <(dd if=/dev/zero bs=1024 count=1024 | pv) | less` also exhibit the behavior so I don't think it's a buffering issue. In any case, since the command piping into pv has closed the output and terminated, `pv` should no longer be buffering.  Along similar lines, `less` can be subbed for `cat` and it still happens (I used `less` to disambiguate the commands I refer to but most of the commands shown are substitutable)

Comment: @arcyqwerty - does it do anything differently if you use `pv -C`?

Comment: `-C` doesn't exist. `-c` still causes deadlock/terminal close on Ctrl-c but clears the terminal when used with `less`.  `cat <(echo; echo | pv -c) | cat` doesn't clear the screen and just has some blank lines (from `echo`?)